# Prepared Statement, Batch Update, Different Updates

Tags: java, jdbc

Is it possible to do a batch update but have different statements? Every tutorial and online resource I find uses the same statement. This is what I have but it's not working.

```
public static void resetNotifications(User user)
{
    DataSource dataSource = null;
    Context initialContext = null;
    Context environmentContext = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    String stride = "UPDATE stride SET recipientView = 1 WHERE recipientId = ?";
    String strideLike = "UPDATE strideLike SET recipientView = 1 WHERE recipientId = ? ";
    String strideCommentMe = "UPDATE strideComment SET recipientView = 1 WHERE recipientId = ? ";
    String strideCommentLike = "UPDATE strideCommentLike SET recipientView = 1 WHERE recipientId = ? ";
    String strideCommentFollow = "UPDATE strideCommentNotification SET recipientView = 1 WHERE userId = ? ";

    try
    {
        initialContext = new InitialContext();
        environmentContext = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        dataSource = (DataSource) environmentContext.lookup("jdbc/instride");
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(stride);
        preparedStatement.setLong(1, user.getId());
        preparedStatement.addBatch();

        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(strideLike);
        preparedStatement.setLong(1, user.getId());
        preparedStatement.addBatch();

        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(strideCommentMe);
        preparedStatement.setLong(1, user.getId());
        preparedStatement.addBatch();

        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(strideCommentLike);
        preparedStatement.setLong(1, user.getId());
        preparedStatement.addBatch();

        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(strideCommentFollow);
        preparedStatement.setLong(1, user.getId());
        preparedStatement.addBatch();

        preparedStatement.executeBatch();
        connection.commit();
    }
    catch(NamingException error)
    {
        System.out.println("NotificationsDAO - resetNotifications() - Error With JNDI Lookup - " + error.getMessage());
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(SQLException error)
    {
        System.out.println("NotificationsDAO - resetNotifications() - Error With SQL - " + error.getMessage());
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (initialContext != null) try{initialContext.close();} catch(NamingException ignore) {}
        if (environmentContext != null) try{environmentContext.close();} catch(NamingException ignore) {}
        if (connection != null) try{connection.close();} catch(SQLException ignore) {}
        if (preparedStatement != null) try{preparedStatement.close();} catch(SQLException ignore) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Try giving table name (and maybe column name also) as parameters.

Comment: See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041410/batch-preparedstatement-with-different-sql-queries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute multiple different statements in a single batch but, you can use a stored procedure that can do it all in a single roundtrip to the server while maintaining the benefits of single transaction

Comment: Awesome, that's what I'll do then. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to execute multiple different statements in one batch if you use a simple `Statement` instead of different `PrepareStatement`s. See documentation and examples [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/statement.html#1000712).

Comment: I guess, not able to execute parametrized queries with `java.sql.Statement` is primary disadvantage as far SQL injection flaws are concerned.